# file_exists returning false when filename is passed through a variable

Tags: php, file, wamp, exists

I'm stumped, and I'm sure I'm missing something really basic here. Safe mode is disabled, the file exists.

This code:

```
$dir = "textfiles"
chdir('../'.$dir."/");
  //using a Windows Slash here(Wamp Stack, on Windows 7 Dev environment

$filename = getcwd() ."\\". $row[0];

       //echoing this outputs: 
       //C:\wamp\www\wordpress\textfiles\New Text Document.txt


$filename = str_replace("\\","\\\\",$filename);

      //echoing this outputs C:\\wamp\\www\\wordpress\\textfiles\\New Text Document.txt
      //escaping slashes in filename to prevent escaping. I SUSPECT my issue may be
      // related to this

    //if (file_exists("C:\\wamp\\www\\wordpress\\textfiles\\New Text Document.txt")) {
            //Line above is commented out, but when it replaces the line below, this thing                       
            //returns True


if (file_exists($filename)) {echo "Yes";} 
   else { echo $filename;}
```

Comment: Is the lack of semicolon in your first line a typo?

Comment: Also, you might want to use the directory constant [**`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`**](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) instead of explicitly writing the separator.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out line

```
/* $filename = str_replace("\\","\\\\",$filename); */
```

And your code should work.

Comment: unfortunately, no. I'd tried that many times, and just did again. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Correction: You are right, and because my data was pulled from a database, it had an erroneous space trailing at the end of the file name. A simple little trim() solved my problem

Comment: Then you need to figure out why there are such spaces ;-)